# SPO synced list

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can someone explain what this sync  icon is?
Some lists have it, others don't. Creating a list from excel or from another site doesn't show this icon. The settings don't point to anything.
I did find some [documentation hinting that lists could be synced](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/common-sync-issues), but how?

[image: sync icon next to favorite]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, on Windows (Windows 10 and later) devices running the OneDrive sync app, lists are available for viewing and editing when you're offline, too. With List sync, we synchronize the list data from the cloud to your Windows device, making fast list operations possible and allowing you to continue your work even when you're offline, you lose your internet connection, or you run into a service disruption in the app.

***Reference:***

**[Edit lists offline](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-lists-offline-41403c3e-1795-4e07-b56b-ae591cbde2f9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**

**[Use Group Policy to control Lists sync settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/lists-sync-policies)**